# Testing the significance of a multiple R value from a multiple regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, multiple-regression, inference

I'm an AP Statistics student (high school senior) doing a final project investigating the correlation between an "overall score" as the response variable and five different "subscores" as explanatory variables (the overall score is NOT calculated from the subscores; rather, each score is given separately). I'm interested in doing some sort of inference (like a hypothesis test) to see if the multiple regression model that I got with my sample data is significant; i.e. I want to see if the model can provide statistically convincing evidence that the population multiple R value is not equal to 0.

Could someone help me by telling me (in detail) how I would go about doing this inference? I only have Excel and RStudio at disposal (although I have *very very* little coding knowledge—almost negligible). I have taken one-variable calculus and have a very basic understanding of multivariable calculus, but I have never taken calculus-based statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in R (RStudio is an Editor for R) you can use the lm()-function to compute a multiple regression. lm() per default provides an F-Test for the $R^2$ value. The null hypothesis of the test is whether $R^2$ is zero (see [here](https://datatofish.com/multiple-linear-regression-in-r/) for a simple example).

Best,
Stefan